# Can I find just the apps which I have purchased in the App Store?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

I know I can go to the Purchased tab in the App Store on my iPad to see all the apps that I have downloaded, but I have been unable to find a way to see *just* the apps that I have *bought*.

Is there a way to sort the apps in the iOS App Store so that one can easily view all the *paid* apps that have been downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do this using the App Store.  I look through my email receipts for this information.

Comment: It the app was purchased using funds loaded by voucher there won't be any email receipts, or will there? I seem to recall only getting receipts when paying by credit card.

Comment: I have quite a few receipts which say "Billed To: Store Credit".

Comment: You're right, I've found that I have ones billed to store credit too. So that's a way I can do this.